# Como criar um formulário dinamico no php

Tags: php, html5, css3

Estou criando um formulário dinâmico que deve funcionar de acordo com o que for selecionado no select.
Não sei o que é, mas a variável tipo_info deve receber o valor do cod_tipo_info e se for igual a 4, ele deve dar um submit e se for uma das outras três opções, vai para parte diferente do formulário.

```
<?php                    
$tipo_info = 0;
echo "<fieldset>Selecione, qual o tipo da informação que deseja cadastrar.<br />";

$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
echo "<select>";
echo "<option></option>";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<option name='ativo' value='".$reg["cod_tipo_info"]."'>".$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]."</option>";
    $tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br /><br />";

while(!$tipo_info == '4') {                           
   if ($tipo_info == '1') {                         
      echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
      break;                             
   } else if ($tipo_info == '2') {
      echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
      break;
   } else if ($tipo_info == '3') { 
      echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
      break;
   }
}

if($tipo_info == '4') {
   echo "<button type=\"submit\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
}
```

Comment: O problema é que ele esta sempre caindo no 4 e esta dando um submit.
Se cair em uma das três opções, o botão faz paginação para inserção dinâmica.

Comment: O seu código de fato funciona, no while ele termina no 4, logo a variável que você colocou lá no laço sempre será 4 (neste caso). Eu usuaria Jquery para resolver seu problema.

Comment: Pode me mostrar como fazer isso?

Comment: O que esta linha quer dizer?
`while(!$tipo_info == '4')` Não deveria ser `while($tipo_info == '4')` Sem o `!`, e no início do código, você atribui `$tipo_info = 0;` Depois compara o campo com strings `$tipo_info == '4'`....

Comment: Enquanto tipo_info for diferente de 4?

Comment: Não porque se for igual a 4 que é o finalizar, deve dar um submit.

Comment: Então deveria ser assim: `while($tipo_info !== '4')`

Comment: Porque você não usa case switch? é mais rápido que o while e os ifs... Fica mais elegante também.

Comment: @fabricio_wm veja se isso ajuda http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/kN84b/2/

Comment: Vou tentar então.
Obrigado.

Comment: Se voce reparar, seu código sempre vai terminar na última opção, ele vai executar ou não o `while`, mas sempre vai continuar para o if no final.

A questão principal, é qual o contexto disto, se for somente isso, pode ser resolvido sem jquery ou javascript mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
<?php                    
$tipo_info = 0;
echo "<fieldset>Selecione, qual o tipo da informação que deseja cadastrar.<br />";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pv_tipo_info_questionario");
echo "<select>";
echo "<option></option>";
while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<option value='".$reg["cod_tipo_info"]."'>".$reg["tipo_info_questionario"]."</option>";
    $tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br /><br />";

switch($tipo_info){

case 1: 
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary     pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break; 
case 2: 
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
case 3: 
    echo "<button type=\"button\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break;
case 4: 
    echo "<button type=\"submit\" disabled=\"true\" class=\"avancar btn btn-primary pull-right\">Avancar</button>";
    break; 
}
```

Comment: Eu não posso usar if no lugar do while pq senao, eu fico com um único item no meu select.
Fiz o switch e case igual ao seu e continua na mesma.

Comment: tem razão, editei a resposta, sempre cai no 4??

Comment: sim.
O 4 é o submit pq o <button type = "submit">. Os outros estão com type=button.
Não fazem nada a não ser paginar.
Obrigado.

Comment: Sempre irá cair no 4 por que no while está definido a seguinte linha $tipo_info = $reg["cod_tipo_info"];

Comment: Outro detalhe que percebi, é que você está nomeando todas as `<option>` com `name="ativo"`, o option não tem essa propriedade.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: Então. como eu faço para atribuir o valor selecionado para a variavel, Diego?

Comment: Pra não fazer da forma que te enviei acima, você precisa enviar o valor para poder mostrar o botão depois, dar um get ou até mesmo post e ai sim mostrar o botão

Comment: Então, eu não entendi o que ele quer obter com esse botão... Porque no while, vai pegar o valor do último registro e verificar no switch ou if ou seja la´ o que for.

Comment: @MarceloAymone, o que ele quer de fato é isso aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/kN84b/2/ selecionar a opção no select e mostrar um botão (enviar ou avançar) no caso desse código ao selecionar o 4 eu já faço o submit

Comment: Também pode-se fazer desta forma com javascript puro, ele vai dando o post na mesma página e no if ele verifica qual foi a opção que enviou ai ele mostra no echo http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/9G6ut/

Comment: Hum, entendi, então realmente precisa usar um post ou javascript, Fabricio, você sabe o que é server side, ou client side? Quando você executa o script, o php não vai aguardar o usuário selecionar, ele já vai usar o valor salvo na última instrução para terminar o script.

Comment: Pessoal.
Essa é uma página que já possui uma programação que faz mais ou menos isso:
http://jsfiddle.net/U7Vvb/
Por isso que eu não queria mexer no javascript ou jquery, a não ser que não interfira no código do link.

Comment: @MarceloAymone. Eu tenho noção.
Acho que o caminho, é esse mesmo. Como podemos fazer?

Comment: Esse aqui, está mas atual e correto.
http://jsfiddle.net/fabricio_wm/U7Vvb/3/

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Eu acessei lá e está funcionando, o que ocorre agora?

Comment: Correto MarceloAymone. Eu coloquei o código no JsFiddle para que você vejá que eu tenho uma programação que já funciona.
Eu preciso fazer a minha ideia funcionar, seja através do PHP, como eu estava tentando ou pelo JavaScript, como mostrou o @DiegoVieira.
O JavaScript, precisa ter a opção de ao escolhe a opção 1, ele vai para um select e se escolher a 2ª opção vai para a uma pergunta com rádio button.
E assim eu tenho um formulário dinâmico.
Obrigado.

Comment: Isso mesmo @MarceloAymone.